# Prime Number Testing

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n\geq2$ is an integer. I claim that there is no prime of the form $100^n+1$. I am trying to find a counter example. Till now I did not find such prime. So my question is: Does there exist a prime number of the form $100^n+1$?

Comment: The only candidates for primality are when $n$ is a power of $2$, so the number to be tested grow very rapidly.

Comment: @user170039 I deleted my comment, I was thinking of a different sequence.

Comment: This appears to be an open question.  These are a subset of the _generalized Fermat numbers_; see http://jeppesn.dk/generalized-fermat.html , which suggests that no other primes of your form are known (but a proof that there are no others is almost surely impossible).

Comment: The given problem is equivalent to find a prime of the form $10^n+1$ with $n>2$.